# NODEJS Loop a object in EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, ejs

I need to access an array(object object) in a EJS page, my setup is displaying an array brought from database.. I've come as far as displaying the object on the page, but when accessing I'm having a hard time..

I'm using the following code:

```
<%  datacollection.forEach(function(data){ %>

    <h1><%=data.name%></h1>
<% } %>
```

but with this I am getting a error:

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in C:\Users\FT\Desktop\foobase-master\project\html\pages\quotes.ejs while compiling ejs

or saying that same code is not a function if I add a ')' where I think it makes sense..

Help!

EDIT: How can I loop through this object array? Already tried a for loop but leaves a blank space, no entries..
**Using this:

```
<ul class="quotes">
  <!-- Loop through quotes -->
  <% for(var i = 0; i < datacollection.length; i++) {%>
    <li class="quote">
      <!-- Output name from the iterated quote object -->
      <span><%= datacollection[i].name %></span>:
      <!-- Output quote from the iterated quote object -->
      <span><%= datacollection[i].quote %></span>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: gota close the forEach `<% }) %>`

Comment: I am now getting an error: datacollection.forEach is not a function

Comment: then `datacollection` is not iterable

Comment: How so? I have this array printed in console of node js, there must be a way to display this info on the browser...

Comment: you'll need to show how you loading datacollection, issue was syntax with caps NODEJS, now browser has entered the mix

Comment: Check comment on answer bellow please...

Comment: which one? Please provide enough info in your question to answer it.

Comment: Here:   {
    _id: new ObjectId("634c33b22ab05cbbbf6ea598"),
    name: 'Francisco',
    nickname: 'T',
    email: 'inaminute20@il.com'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("634c340fcd1993006dab3b63"),
    name: 'FT',
    nickname: 'FT',
    email: 'FT'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("634c3496e87b256da0ab3e6d"),
    name: '111111',
    nickname: 'T',
    email: 'yoox3'
  },

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you forgot to close the foreach ')'. That is why it was showing error of missing closing round bracket.

```
<%  
datacollection.forEach(function(data){ %>

<h1><%=data.name%></h1>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: I am getting an error with that... datacollection.forEach is not a function

Comment: Can you share datacollection object. What values does datacollection have?

Comment: a whole bunch of these: 

 {
    _id: new ObjectId("634c33b22ab05cbbbf6ea598"),
    name: 'Francisco',
    nickname: 'T',
    email: 'inaminu8@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("634c340fcd1993006dab3b63"),
    name: 'FT',
    nickname: 'FT',
    email: 'FT'
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("634c3496e87b256da0ab3e6d"),
    name: '111111',
    nickname: 'T',
    email: 'yoox3'
  },

All entries of me trying out the insert to DB collection

Comment: Check this link: https://onecompiler.com/ejs/3yk5exs24

Comment: You probably not wrapping up the objects into single arrray, and iterating. That's why it is saying forEach is not a function. If you wrap it in a array, then it will work.

Comment: Do you know a different way to loop over the iterations of array? this one gices me a not a function error when compiling ejs... Or better, how do I wrap the array?

Comment: You can follow this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3010848/17791486

Comment: I have just learned that NodeJs outputs a BSON type of array, do you know how to turn to Json?

Comment: Mongo db stores data into BSON format. You can directly do operation on it. If not able to do, then you can use json.stringify that bson and then json.parse. This will generate JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the object as context from the the backend, try this:

```
<% context.datacollection.forEach(function(data) { %>
  <h1><%=data.name%></h1>
<% }); %>
```